# I am creating email form to recieve email from customers. I am stuck in undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass ERROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My controller is

```
class ContactformController < ApplicationController
def new
    @message = Message.new

  end

  def create
    @message = Message.new(params[:message])

    if @message.valid?
     BookingMailer.new_message(@message).deliver
      redirect_to(contactform_path, :notice => "Message was successfully sent.")
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Please fill all fields."
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

My view is

```
<div class="row-fluid wiyo_contact_social">
    <%= form_for @message, :url => contactform_path do |form| %>
  <fieldset class="fields">
    <div class="field">
      <%= form.label :name %>
      <%= form.text_field :name %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= form.label :email %>
      <%= form.text_field :email %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
      <%= form.label :subject %>
      <%= form.text_field :subject %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= form.label :body %>
      <%= form.text_area :body %>
    </div>
  </fieldset>

  <fieldset class="actions">
    <%= form.submit "Send" %>
  </fieldset>
<% end %>
</div>
```

My model is message.rb with database table named "messages"

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base

include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  extend ActiveModel::Naming

  attr_accessor :name, :email, :subject, :body

  validates :name, :email, :subject, :body, :presence => true
  validates :email, :format => { :with => %r{.+@.+\..+} }, :allow_blank => true

  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |name, value|
      send("#{name}=", value)
    end
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end

end
```

My config sniplet

```
 match 'contactform' => 'contactform#new', :as => 'contactform', :via => :get
    match 'contactform' => 'contactform#create', :as => 'contactpost', :via => :post
```

When i put mywebsite.com/contactform, it gives error undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
Please help me.

Comment: Please share the stacktrace and any code from your app which appears in the stacktrace. It's also not clear what you mean by "put mywebsite.com/contactform". Are you talking about an HTTP PUT? Are you talking about "putting" that URL in your browser address field and doing a GET?

Comment: Put means I entered the URL "mywebsite.com/contactfom"

Comment: OK.  Can you post the stack trace and related code?

Answer (score 0):

If the name, email, sub... fields are in the DB, you don't need them as attr_accessor. nor the initialize. ActiveRecord will do that for you